# DFD LEVEL -1: source/sinks and data store are allowed to included?

Tags: software-development

I am trying to develop a DFD level 0 and 1. But as I learned from different sources(eg. textbook, website) that some say data store and sources/sinks are not allowed in the level-1 and the rest of decomposed diagrams, but some say it can be.

Are there any criteria for DFD decomposing development?

Thanks

Comment: Hi hckalewine, welcome. Did you read [here](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/data-flow-diagram/what-is-data-flow-diagram/)?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres thanks! That helps a lot.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - why not summarize & write that as an answer?

Comment: @DannySchoemann done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy to find something useful about it online, I agree. Accordingly to Timothy Arndt and Angela Guercio in *[Decomposition of data flow diagrams](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3512832_Decomposition_of_data_flow_diagrams)*,

> Data flow diagrams are an important design aid in system development.

and

> Decomposition is the top-down development of a data flow diagram
> starting with the system inputs and the system outputs

Personally I liked the content from Visual Paradigm on the matter to know more about DFD. About decomposition, they write

> Top-down decomposition, also called leveling, is a technique used to
> show more detail in lower-level DFDs. Leveling is done by drawing a
> series of increasingly detailed diagrams until the desired degree of
> detail is reached.

In other words, when doing leveling the goal is

> first displaying the targeted system as a single process, and then
> showing more detail until all processes are functional primitives.

When you ask in your question

> some say data store and sources/sinks are not allowed in the level-1 and the rest of decomposed diagrams, but some say it can be

what i extract from that article in Visual Paradigm is that in a context diagram you don't want any data source but in a Level 1 it's fine (there's even one example of it there - see next image).

[image]

In fact, there's some considerations / criteria to have for DFD leveling: unique names for levels, no cross line, numbering convention, ...

I suggest you to have a look as well at [this article from Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/data-flow-diagram-example-food-ordering-system.jsp) which explains DFD by using a food ordering system as an example.